# CUDA bindings for .net?

Tags: .net, interop, pinvoke, cuda, language-binding

I know that there are a lot of CUDA language bindings, such as PyCUDA, but are there any *good* bindings for .Net? The only one I've seen is [this one](http://www.gass-ltd.co.il/en/products/cuda.net/), but I'd like to know if there are any others.

Answer (score 8):

Here's another library: http://sourceforge.net/projects/brahma-fx/

*Edit*: I've been looking at the documentation for the project you initially listed, and can say that the interface makes me think: what is the point of using .Net.  The project I've listed has a cleaner interface but no documentation.  The project you listed seems to be more dedicated in the development path ( a recent 2.1 release), but the SVN of Brahma isn't too old (5 wks).

Another poster listed the Accelerator framework.  It looks *very* promising, although its license is non-commercial (you must contact them if you intend to use it for any commercial work), and when I installed it, it said it installed right and I can't find it on my system (this could have been a Vista issue)!

**EDIT**: I have looked into the various libraries, and can say here is my "recommendations":

1. If you are planning on using LINQ and only .Net 3.5, use Brahma.
2. If you are non-commercial in your goal, use the Accelerator project that the other poster gave (Tim, I believe).  It is higher level than the project you mentioned.
3. If you don't care about low-level details, but very active project and documentation is desired then go with the project you listed.

Comment: Brahma uses HLSL/GLSL, not CUDA.

Answer (score 6):

Microsoft Research has a project called "Accelerator"  http://research.microsoft.com/apps/pubs/default.aspx?id=70250

Comment: Accelerator doesn't use CUDA (uses pixel-shaders).

Comment: This research project is from 2006. Still relevant and interesting though.

Comment: @Contango, it also has a v2 which can be seen at: http://research.microsoft.com/en-us/projects/Accelerator/

Answer (score 6):

Here's another one http://www.hybriddsp.com/Products/CUDAfyNET.aspx

translates .NET code to CUDA C automatically, 
has quite good pack of examples

Answer (score 2):

Checkout this two wrappers:

First the Tidepowerd that allow programming in .NET languages like C#, F#, and VB.NET*
http://www.tidepowerd.com/product

Second the CUDA.NET da Hoopoe,
http://www.hoopoe-cloud.com/Solutions/cuda.net/

Both are discussed here at stackoverflow and have suggestion of sample codes in theirs web sites.
I guess this will help you.